# FireMonkey: Как добавить в ячейку TGrid кнопку?

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно добавить в ячейку `TGrid` кнопку?

Comment: Написать новый компонент TGridWithButton

Comment: Боюсь, что это слишком сложный путь для меня - в FireMonkey я новичок!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена:

```
type
  TBtnCell = class(TStyledControl)
  FBtn : TButton;
private
  class procedure MyClick(Sender: TObject);
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
end;

constructor TBtnCell.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
inherited;
  FBtn := TButton.Create(Self);
  FBtn.Parent := Self;
  FBtn.Align := TAlignLayout.alClient;

  FBtn.Text := 'Click me';
  FBtn.OnClick := TBtnCell.MyClick;
end;

class procedure TBtnCell.MyClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('test');  
end;

type
  TButtonColumn = class(TColumn)
  private
    function CreateCellControl: TStyledControl; override;
  end;

function TButtonColumn.CreateCellControl: TStyledControl;
begin
  Result := TBtnCell.Create(Self);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Grid1.AddObject(TButtonColumn.Create(Grid1));
end;
```